# Reactive form combineLatest object is possibly null or undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'd like to change the value of a FormArrray depending of two others controls.

In my opinion I've made all the checks needed but typescript point me out st and sp

> object is possibly null

What's wrong with this code ?

```
let starterChanges$ = of(null);
    const starter = this.frm.get('starter');
    if (starter) {
      starterChanges$ = starter.valueChanges;
    }
    let spreadChanges$ = of(null);
    const spread = this.frm.get('spread');
    if (spread) {
      spreadChanges$ = spread.valueChanges;
    }
this.subscription.add(
      combineLatest([starterChanges$, spreadChanges$]).subscribe(([st, sp]) => {
        let current = 0;
        if (st !== null && sp !== null) {
          for (const control of this.orders.controls) {
            if (!current) {
              current = current + st + sp;
            } else {
              current = current + sp;
            }
            control.patchValue({ spread: current });
            control.disable();
          }
        }
      })
    );
```

Comment: which line throws this error

Comment: if (!current) {
              current = current + st + sp;
            } else {
              current = current + sp;
            }

Answer (score 1):

This condition is very likely the problem:

```
if (!current) {
  current = current + st + sp;
}
```

If `!current` then how can use use it with `+` operation? This will lead to situations like `null + st + sp` and what's supposed to be the result of this?

Comment: let current = 0; in js 0 ? 'true' : 'false' so  if (!current) catch the first loop and  for current = current + st + sp;  I check the null value with if (st !== null && sp !== null) so it cant be null at max could be a string but not null ----  st and sp are input of type number

Comment: and without the ([st = 0, sp = 0]) also with this code  if (typeof st === 'number' && typeof sp === 'number')  the linter point me out the null value!

Answer (score 0):

Try the next check:

```
if (st && sp) { ... }
```

You are checking if it is null but it can be undefined.

Comment: It was my first attempt but it doesn't work I worked it out with  ([st = 0, sp = 0])

Comment: Is it happening during the compilation or IDEA highlight it as an error? I am asking because sometimes in VS Code TS server is being stuck and shows error even if there are no any issues with code. In this case I am restarting just TS Server in editor.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP to move the answer from the question post)*.

I worked it out with:

```
([st = 0, sp = 0])
```